# React, Redux: how to avoid loading data into the store twice

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

### The Set Up

I have a React/Redux application that loads a list of `cats` from an API.

The data gets loaded into a component like so:

```
// thunk, etc omitted for clarity.
componentDidMount() {
    if(!this.props.loaded){
        this.props.actions.loadRooms();
    }
}
```

Which draws its props from here:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        cats: state.cats.items,
        loaded: state.cats.loaded
    }
}
```

Assume the following:

1) `cats` will be needed in a different, entirely separate component, one that is not a child of the current component.

2) I have no way of knowing which of the `cats` requiring components will be mounted first.

### The Actual Question

Is the `if(!this.props.loaded)` useful? Put another way, does it save me a theoretical call to the API when that other route mounts if both check for existing store data first?

If the check is useful, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I would have your redux actions look something like: `GET_CATS`, `GET_CATS_SUCCESS`, and `GET_CATS_ERROR`.

`GET_CATS` would set the `loading` state in the redux store to `true`, that way you can interrogate it in the respective `componentDidMount()` functions and only make the call to the api when `loading` is false. I think this is a fairly common way of doing it.

Comment: I essentially have this, though `loaded: false` is set in the reducer's `initialState` as opposed to a dedicated `GET_CATS` action.

Comment: @crowhill You will want to track more than just `loaded`. You will want to know if the request has been made. So `loading` is more on point. You will know if the data is loaded merely by seeing if it is there. So a `loaded` key is probably redundant

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you handle your async data fetching in redux ,if both siblings components are listening to the portion of the state that represents `cats` you can do:

```
// Component A and Component B might have something like this
// they both subscribe to the same portion of the state so, if
// data is already available then you don't need to do fetch it again.
...
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.props.cats.length === 0) {
    this.props.actions.loadRooms();
  }
}
...
```

If you are using `redux-thunk` then you might control this at the `action` level:

```
function loadRooms() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {   
    if (getState().cats.length === 0) {
      dispatch(loadRoomsPending());

       fetchMyData(...args)
         .then((res) => dispatch(loadRoomsSuccess(res))
         .catch((err) => dispatch(loadRoomsError(err));
    }
  }
}


// Component A and Component B
...
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.actions.loadRooms();
}
...
```

Again here you have access to the current state with `getState()` so it's pretty common to check if the data is already available. Now this approach comes with some boilerplate and it might get tedious in the long run (it requires for you to write another three functions `loadRoomsPending`, `loadRoomsSuccess`, `loadRoomsError`). This way your components don't have to manually check for it. Or if you like it more explicit or cleaner you can give a middleware I implemented a try, I was kind of frustrated by all this boilerplate so using `redux-slim-async` you can do this:

```
function loadRooms() {
  return {
    types: [
      actionTypes.LOAD_ROOMS_PENDING,
      actionTypes.LOAD_ROOMS_SUCCESS,
      actionTypes.LOAD_ROOMS_ERROR,
    ],
    callAPI: fetch(...args).then(res => res.json()),
    shouldCallAPI: (state) => state.cats.length === 0,
  };
}
```

This handles everything for you with FSA compliant actions and it's very clear what is going on. Heck if you set it up properly you can make it even better:

```
function loadRooms() {
  return {
    typePrefix: actionTypes.LOAD_ROOMS,
    callAPI: fetch(...args).then(res => res.json()),
    shouldCallAPI: (state) => state.cats.length === 0,
  };
}
```

And this will fire off the pending, success and error request with the format `${typePrefix}_PENDING`, `${typePrefix}_SUCCESS`, `${typePrefix}_ERROR`, You can find the middleware [here](https://github.com/Gabri3l/redux-slim-async). But by all means just use whatever you feel best fits your use case, I felt like sharing this work because it's a frustration that brought me to build a middleware to handle it. Keep in mind that I made some assumptions on your case so if I am completely off let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. For option B (do check in thunk), how would you handle the "data's already loaded" case? As in, `getState().cats.length > 0`

Comment: Well it depends on your logic flow, so it really is up to you. You can base it on the length if it's an array or anything else that makes sense for your use case. The problem is that you want to take action only if there is no data available that's why I checked if no data was there. Otherwise if you do `if (getState().cats.length > 0)` then what do you do exactly ? Just nothing ?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to see if a separate class is loaded its data yet. If yes, then don't call the API to load the cats again.

There are two ways to do this, let's assumed COM1 and COM2 are your components.

1. return the entire `state` instead of just the specific variables you want for both of your components:

   return state

then reference the cats in each component:

```
this.props.COM1.cats.items
this.props.COM2.cats.items
```

2. return the specific cats variable from the other components. you do the following for each components:

`function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {`

```
let cats = state.COM1.cats.items;

let loaded: state.cats.loaded;

let otherCats = state.COM2.cats.items;

return {

cats,

otherCats,

loaded

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

well in my case, i just avoid saving data to directly in state and add data inside an object instead.
like before:

```
const initialData = [];
state.push(...);
```

after:

```
const initialData = {
data: []
};
state.data.push(....);
```